# What does disjunct mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, terminology, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

I am trying to understand the definition of a disjunctive normal form. I got this definition from this [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073383090):

> A propositional formula is in disjunctive normal form if it consists
> of a disjunction  of $(1, … ,n)$ ***disjuncts*** where each ***disjunct*** consists
> of a conjunction of $(1, …, m)$ atomic formulas or the negation of an
> atomic formula. Example of what is and what not is a disjunctive normal form:
>
> - Yes $(p∧¬q)∨(¬q∨q)$
> - No $p∧(p∨q)$

I do not know what a disjunct is, so I searched on Google and found that, according to Google, a disjunct is each of the ***terms*** of a disjunctive proposition.

So, I got a new question from this definition of disjunct. What do the ***terms*** of a disjunctive proposition refer to? Specifically, what is the meaning of ***terms*** in this context?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The "disjuncts" are the element of a *disjunction*: either $p \lor q$ or $\varphi \lor \psi$.

Comment: So p, q, , and  are the disjuncts?

Comment: In this example:  (p∧¬q)∨(¬q∨q),



(p∧¬q) is a disjunct of the disjunctive proposition (p∧¬q)∨(¬q∨q), and
(¬q∨q) is a disjunct of the disjunctive proposition (p∧¬q)∨(¬q∨q)? In total, the disjunctive proposition (p∧¬q)∨(¬q∨q) has two disjuncts, i.e., (p∧¬q) and (¬q∨q)?

Comment: @PabloRamosEscalona Yes to both questions.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I got it now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. A **disjunct** of a disjunction is simply one its two inputs. So, $$P\lor Q$$ has disjuncts $P$ and $Q.$
2. The compound disjunction $$P\lor Q\lor R\lor S$$ can be *considered* to have four disjuncts, $P,Q,R$ and $S.$ However, someone literal-minded might argue that it has six distinct disjuncts, including either $(P\lor Q)$ or $(R\lor S),$ depending on whether the sentence is read left-to-right or right-to-left.
3. We do not speak of the "disjuncts" of a sentence like
   $$P\lor Q\lor R\land S\lor T,$$ because.... confusing.

Comment: In (2.) couldn't we say there are 8 disjuncts?

Comment: $(P\lor Q\lor R)$ and $(Q\lor R\lor S)$?

Comment: So *disjunct* is to *disjunction* as *factor* is to *product*, right?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Perhaps .... *term* is to *multiplcation*?  (Technically 'product' refers to the result, while 'factor' suggests an integer.)

Comment: I guess you're right. I was looking for an example of naming the operands that was more familiar. Disjuncts are the “things” you disjoin when you express a disjunction.